# spring-boot gradle thin jar MavenCapsule

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, executable-jar

Is there any alternative to [MavenCapsule](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/us.kirchmeier.capsule) gradle plugin

My spring-boot project is generating a >100MB executable fat jar and is inconvenient to transfer to QA and Production.

Based on [this](https://github.com/danthegoodman/gradle-capsule-plugin#mavencapsule) I created a test/sample spring-boot+ mavenCapsule project and able to generate thin jar which downloads(and cache) dependencies during execution

But it doesn't work for below cases

- dependency without version

  with compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
  I get below error during execution

> ```
> CAPSULE: Transfer failed: capsule.org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:pom:null in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
> ```

- project dependency not packaged

  with compile project(':projects:common-project')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative : https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-thin-launcher

Works fine for sample project, will update after using in real/big project.

Comment: spring-boot-thin-launcher too not working for project with dependency on other project (gradle - compile project ':AnotherProject' )

Answer (score 0):

Check your maven version, I had a similar problem with maven 3.0.x. It has to do with the aether version with maven previos to 3.1.x.

Upgrading to 3.3.x solved the issue.

More information here: https://github.com/chrisdchristo/capsule-maven-plugin/issues/4